# incrementing mod counter every n clock cycle

Tags: verilog

This is the verilog code for mod 64 counter, incrementing every clock cycle

```
module modulus64counter
#(parameter N=64,
parameter WIDTH=5)
(input clk,
input rstn,
output reg[WIDTH-1:0] out);
integer i;
always @(posedge clk) begin
if(!rstn) begin
out<=0;
end
else begin
if(out==N-1)
out<=0;
else 
out<= out+1;
end
end
endmodule
```

and the test bench is

```
module modulus64countertb;

    // Inputs
    reg clk;
    reg rstn;

    // Outputs
    wire [4:0] out;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    modulus64counter uut (
        .clk(clk), 
        .rstn(rstn), 
        .out(out)
    );
    always #10 clk = ~clk;
    initial begin
        // Initialize Inputs
        clk = 1;
        rstn = 0;

        $monitor ("T=%0t rstn=%0b out=0X%h", $time,rstn,out);
repeat(2) @(posedge clk);
rstn <=1;
repeat(50) @(posedge clk);
$finish;
end
endmodule
```

Now if i want to increment the value of **out** every "n" clock cycle instead of consecutive clock cycle , how can i modify the program

Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated 20220131

Updated the code to produce output after every 2 clock cycles. Similarly, if you wish to delay for even more clock cycle, the simplest way is to continuously flopping it.

For a better implementation, you can try out a shift register.

```
module modulus64counter #(
    parameter               N=64,
    parameter               WIDTH=8,
    parameter               DELAY_CYCLE=2
)(
    input                   clk,
    input                   rstn,
    output reg[WIDTH-1:0]   out,
    output reg[WIDTH-1:0]   actual_out
);
    integer                 i;
    reg       [WIDTH-1:0]   cntr;
  
    reg       [WIDTH-1:0]   dly1clk;
    
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if(!rstn) begin
            out <= 0;
            dly1clk <= 0;
        end else if(out == DELAY_CYCLE-1) begin
            out <= 0;
            dly1clk <= dly1clk + 1;
        end else begin
            out <= out + 1;
        end
    end
  
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if(!rstn) begin
            actual_out <= 0;
        end else begin
            actual_out <= dly1clk;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

---

The code below should work for you. You can always swap the `out` and `actual_out` if you insist on using `out` as the final counting variable.

Also, removing the `out` on the `monitor` line in the testbench will only print the value when it reaches `mod n`. I kept both `out` and `actual_out` on testbench's `monitor` to ease debugging purpose.

### Verilog code

```
module modulus64counter #(
    parameter               N=64,
    parameter               WIDTH=8
)(
    input                   clk,
    input                   rstn,
    output reg[WIDTH-1:0]   out,
    output reg[WIDTH-1:0]   actual_out
);
    integer                 i;
    reg       [WIDTH-1:0]   cntr;
    
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if(!rstn) begin
            out <= 0;
            actual_out <= 0;
        end else if(out == N-1) begin
            out <= 0;
            actual_out <= actual_out + 1;
        end else begin
            out <= out + 1;
        end
    end
endmodule
```

### Testbench

```
module modulus64countertb;

    // Inputs
    reg         clk;
    reg         rstn;

    // Outputs
    wire [7:0]  out;
    wire [7:0]  actual_out;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    modulus64counter uut (
        .clk(clk), 
        .rstn(rstn), 
        .out(out),
        .actual_out(actual_out)
    );
  
    always #10 clk = ~clk;
    initial begin
        // Initialize Inputs
        clk  = 1;
        rstn = 0;

        $monitor ("T=%0t rstn=%0b out=%d actual_out=%d", $time,rstn,out,actual_out);
        repeat(2) @(posedge clk);
        rstn <=1;
        repeat(200) @(posedge clk);
        $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

Output result simulated using [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/):
[image]

Comment: Actually this works for incrementing values for consecutive clock cycles, but if i need to increment the counter every 2 clock cycles, then how should i do it? Can you please suggest.

Comment: @elsa, the ```n``` in your question, does it represents```64``` or ```2```? My solution increments the value once every 64 clock cycles, not consecutive cycle. However, if you wanted to increment once every two cycles, you can flop the output, and output it on the second clock cycle.

Comment: @elsa, I have updated my answer to meet your requirements. Also, can you kindly modify your question accordingly?